# Rajuster la mèche qui m’est tombée dans / sur les yeux

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Je me relève sur un coude et rajuste la mèche qui m’est tombée **dans**
> les yeux.

"Dans" convient ici, au sens propre, n'est-ce pas ? Est-ce que "sur" est aussi correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Oui, les deux se disent :

> [...] la mèche qui m'est tombée dans les yeux

> [...] la mèche qui m'est tombée sur les yeux

Et aussi :

> [...] la mèche qui m'est tombée devant les yeux